# How fix driver error for ryzen processors (code 32)?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-ryzen, threadripper

Got exactly the same issue as [this](https://community.amd.com/thread/228919):

> A driver (service) for this device has been disabled. An alternative driver may be providing this functionality. (Code 32)

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Did you click the "Update Driver" button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [thread](https://community.amd.com/thread/228919) contains solving the problem by windows repairment but I have different and easier solution - [Method 2: Reinstall the processor driver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/930861/device-manager-does-not-show-updated-processor-information-on-a-window):

> Use Device Manager to reinstall the processor driver, and then restart the computer. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click StartStart button , type Devmgmt.msc in the Start Search box, and then click Devmgmt.msc.
> 2. In Device Manager, expand the Processors node, and then double-click the first processor that is listed.
> 3. Click the Driver tab.
> 4. Click Update Driver.
> 5. Click Browse my computer for driver software.
> 6. Click Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer.
> 7. Under Model, click the processor that includes the name of the manufacturer of your processor. For example, click the processor that
>      corresponds to Intel, AMD, VIA, or another manufacturer. Click Next.
>      **(here I selected AMD Processor)**
> 8. Click Close.
> 9. Repeat steps 2 through 8 for each processor that is listed under Processors.
> 10. Restart the computer. After the computer is restarted, the correct processor information is listed in Device Manager under Processors.

So all processors core have right driver

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.